# T-SQL2000 and C# Return N records grouped by ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Let me try to explain what Im trying to achieve

Consider the info below:

```
public class RootObj
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public List<string> infoList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to perform just one query a db function that returns to me a list of **RootObj**
Something like this:

```
public List<RootObj> getContactListAddContacts()
{
   ... //get db stuff
   List<RootObj> list = new List<RootObj>();
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      RootObj obj = new RootObj();
      obj.id = (int)dr["table1_id"];
      obj.infoList = ...;//NEED HELP HERE list of table2_id 
      list.add(obj);
   }
   return list;
}
```

and in SQL consider this table

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| id  | table1_id | table2_id |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1         | a         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| 2   | 1         | b         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| 3   | 2         | c         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| 4   | 3         | c         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| 5   | 3         | d         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

The expected Result has to be this one below:

```
list = [
          {
             id:1,
             infoList = {a, b}
          },
          {
             id:2,
             infoList = {c}
          },
          {
             id:3,
             infoList = {c,d}
          }
       ]
```

(Put like json because its easy to see)

How my procedure should looks like to make that happen?

So far cant think better than

```
select table1_id, table2_id from table1_table2
```

but cant think how I will add this to my object just like I want

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although the duplicate question asks about SQL 2005, the accepted answer also works in SQL 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Try linq wit a dictionary :

```
        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> getContactListAddContacts()
        {
           //get db stuff
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("table1_id"), y => y.Field<string>("table2_id"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I could solve using this approach

```
while (dr.Read())
            {
                hasId = false;
                foreach(RootObj cat in list)
                {
                    if(cat.list_id == dr["table1_id"].ToString())
                    {
                        cat.external_ids.Add((string)dr["table2_id"]);
                        hasId = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!hasId)
                {
                    RootObj cat = new RootObj(dr["table1_id"].ToString());
                    List<string> externalList = new List<string>();
                    externalList.Add((string)dr["table2_id"]);
                    cat.external_ids = externalList;
                    list.Add(cat);
                }
            }
```

Thanks anyway **jdweng** for the fast reply